# Tomcat start datetime info

Tags: java, tomcat

is there any simple way how to get information when Tomcat started?
I know that it is in Tomcat log file, but is any other option?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. You can also solve it differently (and container independent!) with help of a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("startupDate", new Date());
    }

    // ...
}
```

This way it's available in any JSP as

```xml
<p>Webapp startup date: ${startupDate}</p>
```

*(formatting can be done with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<fmt:formatDate>`)*

or in any servlet as

```
Date startupDate = (Date) getServletContext().getAttribute("startupDate");
// ...
```